# Stuck on proof of theorem 8.5 of baby Rudins

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $S=(-R,R)$ be an open interval. Let $E$ be a subset of $S$. Let $A$ be the set of all limit points of $E$ in $S$, and let $B$ consist of all other points of $S$. Then it is clear from the definition of "limit point" that $B$ is open.

Why is it clear?

---

The context for this question is a theorem on power series. In the hypothesis of the theorem, $S$ is an open interval upon which two power series converge, and $E$ is the set of points where the two power series converge to the same value. If $E$ has a limit point, the theorem concludes the two power series are (term by term) equal.

Comment: You should probably make your question more self contained. It is unclear what you are actually asking. 8.5 in baby Rudin is about convergent series.

Comment: Hint: limit points of a set are closed.

Comment: @KyleGannon : If this question arose in a proof of a theorem about convergent series, it seems that the fact that that's where it appeared really does not bear upon the question being asked here.

Comment: Rudin defined limit point as topological sence in metric space, so this problem more relevant with topology than convergent series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $a$ is a point in $S$ that is not a limit point of $E.$

That means it is **not** the case that
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0,\quad  \Big( [(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon) \cap S] \smallsetminus \{ a \} \Big) \cap E \ne \varnothing.
$$
Thus the negation of that statement is true:
$$
\exists\varepsilon>0, \quad \Big( [(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon) \cap S] \smallsetminus \{ a \} \Big) \cap E = \varnothing.
$$
Thus every point $a\in S$ that is not a limit point of $E$ has an open neighborhood disjoint from $E.$ Every point in that open neighborhood fails to be a limit point of $E,$ because every point in the open neighborhood $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ has its own open neighborhood that is a subset of $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon).$

Comment: Thank you, I understand it!!

Comment: Can we $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\cap S$ as $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ because $S$ is open set $(-R,R)$.

Comment: $a$ can't be -R or R, so we can search $\epsilon$  such that $[(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)-a]\cap E=\emptyset$ if $a\in B$ .

Comment: @백주상 : Certainly $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon) \subseteq S$ if $\varepsilon$ is small enough.